# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to the python program. I am trying to run the below code

```
import shutil
import os

src = str(input("Enter the path of the file name: "))
dst = str(input("Enter the path of the destination: "))

for (files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filenames in files:
        if files.endswith(".py"):
            shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

But it is giving the below error

```
if files.endswith(".py"):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Please help me in this. Sorry I am asking the very basic question.

Comment: From [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) docs: For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your loop should look like this:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('.'):
```

But more importantly, why are you checking `files` when you're currently iterating through it? You should probably be checking `filenames`.

```
if filenames.endswith(".py"):
```